# What does Python split() function do?

Tags: python

In the following code (line 3), I dont understand why `split('.')[-1]` is used and what it does.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = sde_gdb

for table in arcpy.ListTables():

    t_name = table.split('.')[-1]
    arcpy.TableToGeodatabase_conversion(table, gdb)
```

Comment: This is a question about Python and really doesn't have anything to do with GIS. Specifically, you are asking about the [split function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [list indexing](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists).

Answer (score 3):

The python built in function split() will break apart a string based on the character parameter passed to it and return a list of strings. Lets say your "table" variable has the following value:

```
table = "sde.tblExample"
```

running `table.split('.')` will split the string into a list of two parts:
 `['sde','tblExample']` because you specified to split on the '.' character

If the table value was "dbo.sde.tblExample" `table.split('.')` 
would result in a list of 3 string values: ['dbo','sde',tblExample']

In python you use brackets [] to specify a position within a list. -1 means the last position, and 0 means the first position in a list.

So, running

```
table = "sde.tblExample"
t_name = table.split('.')[-1]
```

will return the list item in the -1 position (or, last position) from the list and pass it to the variable t_name, giving you the result 'tblExample'

Answer (score 2):

`t_name = table.split('.')` will take the content of `table` and break it at each `.` and will save it in the list `t_name`
ex: `public.myTable` ==>  the list will contain two items, `public` and `myTable`

The list index `[-1]` means the last item of the list. Negative indexes counts from the end.

Using the example `public.myTable`, the output `t_name` will be `myTable`.